# How to limit the amount of values within a postgres table which are updated

Tags: postgresql, update, limits

using the following sample:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl(
    x integer, 
    y integer
)

INSERT INTO tbl 
SELECT g AS x FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS g;
```

Which gives:

```
 x  | y 
----+---
  1 |  
  2 |  
  3 |  
  4 |  
  5 |  
  6 |  
  7 |  
  8 |  
  9 |  
 10 |  
(10 rows)
```

I'd like to have something like (*note - I do not care about the ordering of the three values updated in `y` here*):

```
 x  | y 
----+---
  1 |  1
  2 |  2
  3 |  3
  4 |  
  5 |  
  6 |  
  7 |  
  8 |  
  9 |  
 10 |  
(10 rows)
```

I've tried to do this using the following:

```sql
UPDATE tbl 
SET y = x 
WHERE y IS NULL 
LIMIT 3;
```

But I get the error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "LIMIT"`, which I'm not sure how to fix.

## Solution

I think the following works:

```
update tbl 
set y = x 
where x in (select x from tbl where y is null limit 3);
```

I can't think of a scenario this would fail, if there's a better approach it'd be good to know.

Answer (score 4):

Using [common table expressions or CTE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/) might be a good solution, more dynamically (easily changed if the conditions of the updated pattern are modified ) , in terms of performance it should be tested.

Use,

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT x 
    from tbl
    where y is null
    limit 3
)
UPDATE tbl
SET y = cte.x
FROM cte
WHERE tbl.x = cte.x ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/3h9Zqili